# Connect QTimer with a Slot with parameters

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtimer

I tried the following:

```
connext(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &myClass::myMethod(_param1, _param2)); // does not work
timer.setSingleShot(true);
timer.start(100);
```

The timer of type QTimer is a member element of the class.

Is there a way to connect the timeout() signal of a timer to a method with multiple parameters?

Comment: Use a lambda-function as slot.

Comment: Use lambda and pass the arguments you need.

Comment: @ixSci Thanks! Are there any downsides or things to consider when using a lambda in this way?

Comment: Nope, that's a perfectly valid usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QTimer`'s timeout signal `void timeout()` does - on its own - not have enough parameters to call `myClass::myMethod(_param1, _param2);` (where exactly should timeout take `_param1` & `_param2` from?)

You can either use a lambda function:

```
//assuming you have _param1 & _param2 as variables before this point
connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [=]() { myMethod(_param1, _param2); });
timer.setSingleShot(true);
timer.start(100);
```

One thing to note is that by using `this` as the receiver object for `connect()` you tie the lifetime of the connection to both the lifetime of the timer AND of the currect object (`this`), which should ensure that the connection is properly destroyed if one of the two objects dies and the lambda (with its implicit call to `this->myMethod()`) is not executed after `this` is deallocated.

Or you could create a `void myClass::handleTimeout()` function in your class, connect the timeout of the time to it as slot and **there** call `myMethod(_param1, _param2)`

```
void myClass::handleTimeout()
{
    //assuming _param1 & _param2 are variables accessible in handleTimeout()
    myMethod(_param1, _param2));
}

//Your original function...
void myClass::someFunction()
{
    //...
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &myClass::handleTimeout);
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    timer.start(100);
    //...
}
```